# Axe value without decimal

Tags: python, numbers

I have a matplotlib figure which I am plotting data that is always referred to 0 or 1. I do not want other value in the x axe.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tic
import csv
import numpy as np



nq=['peter', 'mary', 'carol']

hist_q=[1,0,1]


y_pos = np.arange(len(hist_q))
plt.figure(1, [5, 20])
plt.ylim(-0.5,max(y_pos)+1)
plt.xlim(0,1)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major')
plt.barh(y_pos, hist_q, align='center', alpha=0.3, label="Names")
plt.yticks(y_pos, nq)
plt.xlabel('Presence')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
fig="s"
plt.savefig(fig,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure()
fig.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to remove the numbers of xticks. Try to insert the following code segment to your code before 'savefig'.

```
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off') # labels along the bottom edge are off
```

BTW, numpy was imported twice in your posted code.